# How to measure the CPU utilization of Each container in Mesos?

Tags: containers, monitoring, cpu-usage, mesos, marathon

I have many apps running on containers in Mesos, managed via marathon. I have given CPU allocation for each app while deploying via marathon like 1, .5 etc.
But the CPU allocation in marathon, does not mean that its 1 CPU or half CPU. It simply means that its time sharing ratio. Also each container gets to access all the CPUs on its Host.

Now, I want to measure the CPU efficiency of each Container on Mesos slaves, so that I can reduce or increase the CPU allocation in for each App in Marathon. I just want to make resource utilisation even more efficient.

I could use https://github.com/bobrik/collectd-mesos-tasks, but the problem is CPU utilisation metrics does not relate to the CPU allocation in Marathon.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: The question is perfectly fine for SO. It's about getting perf data off of Mesos/Marathon which is as relevant for developers as it is for admins.

Comment: Thank you @micheal

Answer (score 4):

In Mesos WebUI you can see how much CPU is used by your executor

[Here](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/81cd023eb9945a22c220edc966393dcfcdbce256/src/webui/master/static/js/services.js#L109-L150) is the code that collects statistics from [`/monitor/statistics`](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/endpoints/slave/monitor/statistics/) endpoint and calculate CPU usage.

You are interested in `cpus_total_usage` so the following method should works for you

Let's assume `a` and `b` are snapshot of statistics at some point in time. To calculate `cpus_total_usage`, we need calculate the time executor spent in the system and user space and divide it by the time elapsed between `a` and `b`.

```
cpus_total_usage = (
                    (b.cpus_system_time_secs - a.cpus_system_time_secs) +
                    (b.cpus_user_time_secs - a.cpus_user_time_secs)) / 
                    (b.timestamp - a.timestamp)
                   )
cpu_percent      = cpus_total_usage / cpu_limit * 100%
```

Comment: cpus_total_usage itself gives us the percentage isn't it? I did not understand what is the cpu_limit in this context. Nice Idea though. Thanks

Comment: Yes and no :) `cpus_total_usage` could be interpreted as percent of one CPU is more like load. It will be more than 1 for more than one CPU that's why I divided it by `cpu_limit` to get a percent of allocated resources and again this value could be grater than 100% because floating point math error and enabled soft limits (by default CFS is disabled)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how much work you want to invest yourself, you can either use the Marathon [Event Bus](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/event-bus.html) and more generally the Marathon HTTP API (for example [this endpoint](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/generated/api.html#v2_apps__app_id__tasks_get)) along with low-level tools like [cAdvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor) or [cinf](https://github.com/mhausenblas/cinf) to do the maths yourself. If you don't want to code stuff yourself, I suggest you use [Sysdig](https://support.sysdigcloud.com/hc/en-us/articles/207886103-Sysdig-Install-Mesos-Marathon-DCOS), [Datadog](http://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/marathon/) or [Prometheus](https://www.antonlindstrom.com/2015/02/24/monitoring-mesos-tasks-with-prometheus.html) to do the heavy lifting for you.